# How can I get the innerText of Dynamic Html tags using Puppeteer.js (node.js) in TripAdvisor?

Tags: html, node.js, chromium, puppeteer

**How would I get all 10 comments located in this page with a loop or a Puppeteer function https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294308-d3937445-Reviews-Maki-Quito_Pichincha_Province.html using `innerText` property?**

**The only solution I have come up with is getting the outerHTML of the whole container of comments and then try to substring to get all the comments, but that is not optimal and I think its a more difficult approach. Maybe there is an easier solution in Puppeteer I cant find?**

I am doing this for educational purposes. The comments are in **`class="partial_entry"`** and I want to get the innerText of a Dynamic Html tag (I want all 10), like the ones you see here:

[image]

If I where to open the div that contains `<div class="review-container" data-reviewid="606551292" data-collapsed="true" data-deferred="false"><!--trkN:3-->`, I would get another  with `id="review_582693262"`. Getting to the point, If I get to a `<div>` that has **`class="partial_entry"`** this would be where my comment is located. I have tried a few things but I get null, because it is not found since the parent `<div>` for each comment has a unique id like `id="review_xxxxxxxxx"`.

Its kind of difficult since the review id is `autogenerated` like `id="review_xxxxxxxxx"` and cant iterate with a loop copying the CSS path since I dont have a static parent .

Comment: Does a wildcard css selector work? i.e. `[id*="review_"]`

Comment: I'll try this tonight, I think it may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just select those elements which have `partial_entry` class? This works:

```
let comments = await page.evaluate(() =>
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".partial_entry")].map(item => item.textContent)
);
```

[image: how this works]

Comment: I found the solution to my problem by counting all the tags that have 'partial_entry', but this is better since I specifically need to use the class like ".partial_entry" in your solution. Thx.